# Is it possible to use multiple packages in the <queries> tags in the Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have 4 Apps: A,B,C,D, i want the App "A" to communicate with the other 3 apps "B,C,D", can i add multiple packages in the  tag in the manifest file of App "A" as shown below ?

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.appB.app" />
    <package android:name="com.appC.app" />
    <package android:name="com.appD.app" />
</queries>
```

Thanks,

Comment: That should work. Did you encounter problems with it?